# How to give same day numbers for all same dates present in array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need to increase day count only if date change.(same date= same day count)

***Input:-***

```
{"employees":[
  {"day":1,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":2,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":3,"date":"2019-09-02T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" },
  {"day":4,"date":"2019-09-03T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":5,"date":"2019-09-03T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":6,"date":"2019-09-04T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }    
]}
```

***Ouput:-***

```
{"employees":[
  {"day":1,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":1,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":2,"date":"2019-09-02T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" },
  {"day":3,"date":"2019-09-013T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":3,"date":"2019-09-013T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":4,"date":"2019-09-04T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }     
]}
```

Comment: it will always be in sorted manner ? or dates can be in any random order ?

Comment: please ad data **and** the matching wanted result - and your try.

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I'm guessing the second example is the one you want it to look like? That one changes the day number only if the date is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the last date and the actual and inclrement the day counter.

```js
var data = { employees: [{ day: 1, date: "2019-09-01T18:15:00", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }, { day: 2, date: "2019-09-01T18:15:00", firstName: "Anna", lastName: "Smith" }, { day: 3, date: "2019-09-02T18:15:00", firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Jones" }, { day: 4, date: "2019-09-03T18:15:00", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }, { day: 5, date: "2019-09-03T18:15:00", firstName: "Anna", lastName: "Smith" }, { day: 6, date: "2019-09-04T18:15:00", firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Jones" }] },
    day = 0;
    result = { employees: data.employees.map((o, i, { [i - 1]: p = {} }) => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { day: o.date === p.date ? day : ++day }
    )) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `reduce`. Set `day` to `1` for first entry. 
For next element, check if the date is equal to previous one, if yes then set the day same as previous one else increment it's day count.

```js
const input = [
  {"day":1,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":2,"date":"2019-09-01T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":3,"date":"2019-09-02T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" },
  {"day":4,"date":"2019-09-03T18:15:00", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
  {"day":5,"date":"2019-09-03T18:15:00", "firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith" },
  {"day":6,"date":"2019-09-04T18:15:00", "firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones" }
];

const output = input.reduce((accu, {day, date, ...rest}, i) => {
    if(i==0) accu.push({"day": 1, date, ...rest});
    else {
        if(date === accu[i-1].date) {
            accu.push({"day" : accu[i-1].day, date, ...rest})   
        } else {
            accu.push({"day": accu[i-1].day + 1, date, ...rest});
        }
    }
    return accu;

}, []);

console.log(output);
```